# Error while displaying image in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, display

First of all, i read tons of posts regarding this but i can't manage to get this working.
I'm really new to jsp and web apps. All i wanna do is to display a simple image.
I have this code in the servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
    String filePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("image.jpg");
    System.out.println(filePath);
    sesion.setAttribute("image", filePath);
    response.sendRedirect("products.jsp");
}
```

And this code in the jsp:

```
<img alt="logo" src="${image}"/>
```

And the folders in my web app are this:
[folders image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiTyU.png)

And finally, when my page loads, this is what i get:
[image does not display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPKK3.png)

I wonder what is the error here? Why it is so complicated (maybe it's not, but i really tried many ways and non of them worked) to display a simple image?

Thanks in advance for your help!

PS: the folder is correct, it prints without problem in the println()

Comment: Use firebug in Firefox or developer tools in Chrome, right click on the image and inspect what is the value of `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getRealPath() gets you the real path in the file system.

When you reference any resource (image, js, css) inside a web it is supposed to be accesible via web.

If you click "view source code" in your browser you'll probably see the fil system path in the  tag:

```
<img alt="logo" src="C:/whatever-your-path-is/image.jpg"/>
```

But what you need is the url path (full or relative) of the resource.

Try this instead:

```
sesion.setAttribute("image", "resources/images/image.jpg");
```

Comment: I feel so dumb right now. Thank you, this is the answer.

Comment: Haha, don't worry, it happens in the best families too. I was once have an hour wondering why "S" == myVar (which values was "S") was false. Glad to help 